# How can i delete the __MACOSX folder in android?

Tags: java, android

My app need to download some ZIP files to work. Once the file has been unzipped, it also reveal the __MACOSX folder, because the original file has been zipped with mac. I know that I can zip the file using the terminal to avoid that folder, but because I have lot of files, for me is better to delete this folder once the file has been unzipped.
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    private static final File MAC_FOLDER = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/folder/__MACOSX");
    File fileMac = MAC_FOLDER;
    if(MAC_FOLDER.exists()){
    fileMac.delete();
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

It doesn't work even if try to delete the folder and hi content

```
  File fileMac = MAC_FOLDER;
     if(MAC_FOLDER.exists()){

         if (fileMac.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = fileMac.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    new File(fileMac, children[i]).delete();
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? It cannot find the directory? Or the delete method is failing? Please provide more details.

Comment: @JoelWitteveen it doesn't work because it's a directory and it's not empty.

Comment: the directory is empty, it found the directory, but don't delete it

Comment: @Bombolo usually `__MACOSX` folders are not empty, they are filled by the system with hidden files. So, are you really sure it is empty?

Comment: well, in my android device looks empty, but i think you are right. Maybe there's some hidden files, i did not think about that, let me try..

Comment: i've try, nothing happen

Comment: Well, the new code won't work if the `__MACOSX` directory contains any non-empty directories. You should confirm what really is the content of that directory by some other means than trying to blindly remove it after it has been copied on a mobile device's storage.

Comment: ...and if you have control over that zip file, I believe it would be less hard work to avoid including that `__MACOSX` directory in the first place.

Comment: Post the "solution" as an answer. Don't edit your post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using this method

```
public void deleteMacosxDirectory(final File MAC_FOLDER) {
      // check if folder file is a real folder
      if (MAC_FOLDER.isDirectory()) {
          File[] list = MAC_FOLDER.listFiles();
          if (list != null) {
              for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                  File tmpF = list[i];
                  if (tmpF.isDirectory()) {
                      deleteMacosxDirectory(tmpF);
                  }
                  tmpF.delete();
              }
          }
          if (!MAC_FOLDER.delete()) {
            System.out.println("can't delete folder : " + MAC_FOLDER);
          }
      }
  }

  File fileMac = MAC_FOLDER;
    if(fileMac.exists()){
          deleteMacosxDirectory(fileMac);
   }
```